# Does `/messages` in Graph API include shared mailboxes?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, office365api, office365-exchange

I'm calling `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id}/messages/` to paginate through all user messages. I'm using app permissions for access, which works fine.

But I'm getting more messages than expected, and I'm not sure why. Is it possible the `/messages` endpoint includes messages from shared mailboxes available to `user_id`, too?

If so, what is the way to suppress that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Microsoft's [Known Issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues#get-messages-returns-chats-in-microsoft-teams) page:

> ## GET messages returns chats in Microsoft Teams
>
> In both the v1 and beta endpoints, the response of GET /users/id/messages includes the user's Microsoft Teams chats that occurred outside the scope of a team or channel. These chat messages have "IM" as their subject.

So the solution is to ignore all messages with `subject == "IM"`.

Answer (score 1):

What gives you the impression that you are getting more messages than is expected? Note that `/messages` [returns all of the messages in the mailbox across all of the folders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

The documentation states that shared message access is performed with [delegated permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-share-messages-folders). You shouldn't be seeing shared messages when using application permissions. Does your application use the `Mail.Read.Shared` or `Mail.ReadWrite.Shared` scopes? If so, you should be able to remove them and I'd expect it shouldn't have access.

Comment: Thanks. No `Mail.Read.Shared`, but I found a likely explanation. See my answer.